# Nuxt/Vue Why is it using client-only component for displaying user data which from firebase auth?

Tags: vue.js, firebase-authentication, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I sometimes find client-only component for displaying user data which is approved with Firebase Auth, in GitHub repositories.

```html
<client-only>
  <pre>
   {{ firebaseUser }}
  </pre>
</client-only>
```

And I just wonder why it needs client-only component, is that because of security thing?

I really hope someone explain for me, thanks.

Comment: Because server cannot authenticate self as a user?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the first part, maybe a cache or alike. Pretty hard to help without more details.

As for the client only component, this one is mainly used for things that are not compatible with SSR. Like a drag and drop zone or something that relies purely on some client side code (often using `window`).

In your code example, it doesn't look like it's needed since it's mostly for some components that do not support SSR.

Also, some places may not need SEO (like personal secure stuff), so putting them in a client only removes then from the server side generation.

Comment: "some places may not need SEO (like personal secure stuff), ~~"

That explanation makes sense!, that I probably needed for my confusion.

These codes like my example are sometimes found in Github with searching words like 'Nuxt3 SSR firebase auth starter'.

Comment: When I try to learn about Vue/Nuxt, I always read docs and thousand articles, and I also found your explanations about hydration mismatch things, using window, and so on. But one day, an article got me confused, which says that important data such as user data should not be rendered on server side. And it doesn't explain why, so I was afraid because of security field. But now I understand, Thank you!

Comment: @mmmchese yeah, if you render it on the server it means that you can basically avoid any kind of security by disabling JS on the page. Since the content coming from the backend is _static_ (regarding the output files), you will still see the actual secure thing of the user. It's like Facebook, imagine your feed being accessible publicly by doing to `facebook.com/users/123/my-feed`. Nah, rather it's your own thing that is rendered on `facebook.com/my-feed`, with client-side calls only. It would be also quite too much work to generate such pages for everybody all day every day.